# Running a mapreduce job fails (File does not exist.)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hdfs

I **tried to run a mapreduce job** and I get the following exeption

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:8020/usr/local/hbase/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.5.1.jar

The **local path** /usr/local/hbase/lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.5.1.jar **is correct**, and the file exists there. However, the **file is expected in HDFS** (where nothing is to be found).

How do I change this path?

Cheers

Comment: Can you write the command you're running

Comment: `hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.seperator=';' -Dimporttsv.columns="id,name:type,location:location,location:lat,location:lon,time,p1:value,p1:dur,p1:ratio,p2:value,p2:dur,p2:ratio" sensor_sds011 hdfs://localhost:8020/home/hbase/2018-01-01_sds011_sensor_926.csv`


Now I `-put` the missing directory into hdfs and it worked (but I feel like that's not the way it's supposed to be).